# Does my app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA) if I use admob?

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect, idfa

Does my app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA) if I use admob latest sdk?
Simple yes or no? Could not find this answer on google.

If YES, then what I have to select here? My previous build had no ads.

[image]

Comment: Yes and select Server Advertisements within the app and Accept terms and conditions

Comment: any reference ? experience ? are you sure ? i don't want my build being rejected :/ also my previous build had no ads.

Comment: experience. I use admob for my 20 + apps. If you only use for showing advertisment use first checkbox else need to mark checkbox for other optios as well.. If you use Admob and don't check it your apps get rejected.

Comment: thank you! what about Export Compliance? I selected "No". Also does this IDFA affects to review process being late ? Normally it takes 4-5 days.

Comment: Export Compliance sorry no idea... IDFA doesn't affect review process timelines

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes:

> The Mobile Ads SDK for iOS utilizes Apple's advertising identifier (IDFA). The SDK uses IDFA under the guidelines laid out in the iOS developer program license agreement. You must ensure you are in compliance with the iOS developer program license agreement policies governing the use of this identifier.

Here's a link with the statement from Google: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download?hl=de